# Saving different values with same key in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a `depoCinsiList` which has the following values:

```
["D","S"]
```

I want to have a **structure like this**:

```
[{type: "D"}, {type: "S"}]
```

I have tried achieving this by using Map.

```
List<String> typeList = typeService.getDepoCinsiList(); //list which returns ["D","S"]

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for (int j = 0; j < typeList.size(); j++) {
    map.put("type", typeList );
}   

ArrayList<Map<String, List<String>>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, List<String>>>();
mapList.add(map);
```

However, this returns as follows:

```
"type":["D","S"]
```

Which data structure I should use to achieve list as `[{type: "D"}, {type: "S"}]`? I could use maybe JSON but I don't want to use additional libraries like gson.

Comment: Doesn't the data structure you're using hold the data you need?  What is the actual need for the proposed structure here?

Comment: try `stringbuffer` that will append every data with `type` keyword ,its simple

Comment: If everything in the list will have the same indicator `type`, does it need to be there at all?

Comment: @takendarkk I need the structure as I mentioned. I will the structure for JS. Otherwise I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: How can we know that? Explain in your question specifically why you **have** to use this structure and nothing else.

Comment: @takendarkk you don't have to know why I need this structure. I will use it in combobox and read it from proxy. This is irrelevant information.

Comment: Nevermind then... good luck with whatever this is.

Comment: @supaplexy: The structure you want contains the following information: "There are two 'type' values, 'D' and 'S'".  The structure you *have* contains *exactly the same information*.  It's not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish here or what the problem is.  This is very relevant information.

Comment: @David It is about how I display the information. Now I display it like '"type":["D","S"]' but I want to display it [{type: "D"}, {type: "S"}]. If you read more carefully, you will see.

Comment: @supaplexy: There is no code in the question which displays anything.  (If you read it more carefully, you will see that.)  What prevents you from writing code which displays the data how you want to display it?  You have the data you need, you can display it however you like.  What have you tried?  What isn't working?  You've set your mind to an incorrect solution that you want us to give you.  That won't work.  Present the *actual problem* being solved, not your imaginary solution that you're trying to force.

Comment: @David You put it into words for me perfectly - "_Present the actual problem being solved, not your imaginary solution that you're trying to force_" I did not know how to say it.

Comment: @takendarkk: It's a surprisingly common phenomenon here: http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2013/10/the-left-turn-at-albuquerque.html  :)

Comment: @takendarkk I'm sure there are better ways to spend your time than downgrading all of my questions :) But I don't mind, you just make me laugh.

Comment: *I'm sure there are better ways to spend your time than downgrading all of my questions*  **its not a single man who voted you**

Comment: @David thanks for that article , just bookmarked it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is my "imaginary solution"

```
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

for (int j = 0; j < typeList.size(); j++) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("type", typeList.get(j));
    list.add(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Map doesnt allow duplicated keys

I like @Zeromus solution but i would go for  [Guava's multimaps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score -1):

you could also create your own Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class Typed {
        private String type;
        public Typed(String type){
            this.type= type;
        }
        public String getType(){
            return this.type;
        }

    }

    List<Typed> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(new Typed("D"));
    myList.add(new Typed("S"));

}
```